# std::list cannot find type

Tags: c++, list

I wrote own realization of Hashmap. As base type I use

```
template <class K, class V>
class HashMap{
public:
    HashMap(){ table.reserve(100); }

    bool insert(const K& key, const V& value) {
        size_t index_pos = find_hash_position(key);
        table[index_pos].push_back(std::make_pair(key, value));
        return true;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::list<std::pair<K, V>>> table;
};
```

Then I try creation of Hashmap and insert a value into:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<std::pair<int, int>, int)> hash_table;
hash_table.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1), 2);
```

But I have an `139` error and

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff768a58f in std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> Cannot find type std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int> > >::iterator::_Node: 
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> Cannot find type std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int> > >::iterator::_Node:
```

What did I wrong and how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Your vector is of zero size when you try to access its element at index_pos

Comment: @PiotrNycz In constructor I reserve a space for vector.

Comment: You should use `resize` instead of `reserve`

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich I bet doing this: `table.at(index_pos).push_back(std::make_pair(key, value));` gives you a more informative diagnostic.

Comment: The problem seems to be have been solved, but what are those `Python Exception`s?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich -- *In constructor I reserve a space for vector.* -- Even if you did do the "right thing" and used `resize()`, how does your code guarantee that `index_pos` does not exceed `vector::size() - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting segmentation fault because your vector is on zero size.
std::vector intially dont allocate any space, their space gets expanded every time you push something in it.

So you should check your "index_pos", resize your vector if it is index is more than vectors capacity.

```
bool insert(const K& key, const V& value) {
    size_t index_pos = find_hash_position(key);
    if(index_pos >= table.size())
    {
        table.resize(index_pos+1);
    }
    table[index_pos].push_back(std::make_pair(key, value));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it can fail if `vector::capacity` is larger than `vector::size`, and `index_pos` is a value between `size` and `capacity`.

Comment: Thanks!! Edit   if(index_pos >= table.size())

Comment: You can fix your answer directly instead of putting the edit in the comment section.

Comment: This is not perfect implementation. For hash map we cannot aford to have unlimited size of the first table. Is should be something like `table.resize(N);` and `table[index_pos % N]....` - otherwise with big enough index_pos one get bad_alloc